# Unable to make connections to more than 6k queues in RabbitMq using node js

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am quite new to Node js and RabbitMq. I wanted to create 100k queues. but I am getting the following error after creating around 6ooo queues.

> error: "Cannot read property 'createChannel' of undefined"

I want to call conn.createConnection() method again if I have an error. How to do this?

Here's the code

```
var amqp = require("amqplib/callback_api");
var time = 0;
var limit = 100000
var timer = setInterval(() => {
  time+=1;
  if(time>=limit){
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  var now = Date.now()
  //RabbitMQ
  amqp.connect("amqp://localhost",function(err,conn){
    conn.createChannel(function(err,ch){
      if(err){
        //try to do conn.createChannel again
      }
      var q = "queue_name"+time.toString();
      // console.log(q);
      var msg = "this is the message string!!!";
      ch.assertQueue(q,{durable: false});
      ch.sendToQueue(q,new Buffer(msg),{persistent: false});
      // console.log("time = "+time);
    });
  });
  //RabbitMQ`
},10);
```

Comment: By reading the given error message i would assume that "amqp.connect" does inject an empty value into the parameter "conn" which leads to given error when calling "createChannel" on "conn" which some sort of empty/null-ish value.

Check whats inside "err" i assume the connection onto "amqp:://localhost" is not established successfully and therefore no "conn" object can be delivered.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not only creating 100k queues, but also 100k connections and channels. Likely you are running out of file handles and you can adjust the ulimit to allow more. However, you probably don't want to create all those connections and channels.

Try using one connection with one publisher channel with something along these lines:

```
var amqp = require("amqplib/callback_api");
var time = 0;
var limit = 100000

amqp.connect("amqp://localhost", function(err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Somethings wrong with connection:', err);
        return;
    }
    conn.createChannel(function(err, ch){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Somethings wrong with channel:', err);
            return;
        }

        var timer = setInterval(() => {
            time+=1;
            if(time>=limit) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            var now = Date.now()
            var q = "queue_name"+time.toString();
            var msg = "this is the message string!!!";
            ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false} );
            ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg),{persistent: false});
            console.log('sent', time);
        },10);
    });
});
```